# Suppose we want to express the point $(2,3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the solution space of a linear system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm in the middle of figuring out how to do this question:

> Suppose we want to express the point $(2,3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the solution space of a linear system of equations.
>
> (a) What is the smallest number of equations you would need? Write down such a system.
>
> (b) Can you add one more equation to the system in (a), in such a way that the new system still has the unique solution $(2,3)$?
>
> (c) What is the maximum number of distinct equations you can add to your system in (a) to still maintain the unique solution $(2,3)$?
>
> (d) Is there a general form for the equations in (c)?

I tried to figure this out. Specifically for question (c), I do understand that we are given a line. In order to have a unique solution, we need another line that can intersect the original one. But now I'm having doubts whether the maximum number of distinct equations is infinite? Because technically our solution is the intersection point, and any "random lines" that go through this point is considered a solution. Am I right?

Comment: I've added math notation to your question (write symbols between dollar signs: $ to use it) This makes your question more readable. Please use it in your future questions

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for c you can add as many lines as you want that go through $(2,3)$ and still have it solve all the equations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've already solved (a) and (b). Am I right? Anyway, (a) is a bit unclear, as anyone would think of $$x=2; y=3$$ as their system, which already defines (2,3) as the unique solution (when someone asks me to "define" something, I understand it means to define it unambiguously. Otherwise, why not just no equations at all as an answer for (a)). But let's say we answered $2y=3x$ for (a) and $x=2$ for (b), which is probably what is being looked for

The answer to (c) depends on whether you consider $x=2$ and $2x=4$ as different equations. Since nothing is said about "linaer independence" of the equations, we can assume that, indeed, you can keep adding extra equations (just multiply both sides of the ones you have by any constant)

As for (d), someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but any "extra" equation would be a linaer combination of those defined in (b)

Answer (score 0):

For (d) the expected equation is $$a(x-2)+b(y-3)=0$$

For $a,b\neq 0$ we have all lines passing through $(2,3)$, because when $x=2$, we have to solve $b(y-3)=0$ and since $b\neq 0$ then $y=3$ (same for $x$ if we set $y=3$ first).

For $a=0$ or $b=0$ we get the two lines // to coordinate axis $x=2$ and $y=3$.

And finally for $a=b=0$ we get the equation $0x+0y=0$ or simply the tautology $0=0$ which represents the entire $\mathbb R^2$ plane (i.e. $x,y$ can take any value).